# Problemas com FolderBrowserDialog. Aplicação trava

Tags: c#

Tenho um aplicativo(WPF) que está funcionando há uns 2 meses sem problemas. Precisei fazer uma alteração. Ao fazer, na linha em que deveria escolher um folder para guardar o resultado da minha aplicação, a aplicação trava(parece que se perde). Isso começou ontem. Fui pra casa e hoje, na primeira hora, consegui fazer funcionar. Depois que funcionou, a partir daí não funcionou mais, voltando a dar o erro. Se comento a linha e fixo um folder, a aplicação funciona(óbvio). Essa é a linha que trava:
`if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)`.

Abaixo o código completo do método:

```
private void CriarZip()
    {
        string path_destino = string.Empty;
        string path_files = caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp";   

        System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();

        fbd.Description = "Selecione a pasta para armazenar o arquivo zipado.";
        fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
        fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = true;

        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            path_destino = fbd.SelectedPath;

        List<string> _filesDiretory = new List<string>();

        string nome_arquivo = nome_arquivo_zip + ".zip";

        if (!nome_arquivo.Contains(".zip"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O nome do arquivo deve possuir a extensão .zip");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            string[] files_new = Directory.GetFiles(path_files, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] folder_new = Directory.GetDirectories(path_files, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            CriaPastaFarmInterna();
            CriaPastaFarmExterna();

            //Deleto os arquivo que não estão na Farm Externa
            foreach (var file in files_new)
            {
                string t = string.Empty;
                int pos = file.IndexOf(dirInicio);

                if (pos > 0)
                {
                    t = file.ToString().Substring(pos, file.Length - pos);

                    bool bListaArquivo = (from b in listaArquivosForaFarmExterna
                                          where b.Contains(t)
                                          select b).Count() > 0 ? true : false;
                    if (bListaArquivo)
                        File.Delete(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    t = Path.GetFileName(file);
                    arquivos.Add(t);
                }  

            }

            LimpaPastaWeb();
            DeletaPastaFarmExterna();

            //Adiciono arquivos que estão dentro da pasta base apenas
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path_files))                    
            {
                arquivos.Add(file);
            }

            //Aqui pego as pastas com arquivos que serão zipadas
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetDirectories(path_files))
            {
                arquivos.Add(file);
            }

            string localNomeDestinoZIP = path_destino + "\\" + nome_arquivo;

            if (arquivos.Count() > 0)
            {

                processaDiretorio(path_files);
                ZipUnzip.CriarArquivoZip(arquivos, localNomeDestinoZIP);
                MessageBox.Show("Os arquivos selecionados foram compactados na pasta \n\n " +
                          localNomeDestinoZIP);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Não há a pasta para ser compactada.");                

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao criar arquivo ZIP \n\n " + ex.Message);
            //zipgif.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        finally
        {
            DeletarPastaTrabalho(caminho_original);
            //zipgif.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

tente acrescentar nas referências:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

e depois instanciar da seguinte maneira:

```
DialogResult result = new DialogResult();

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    path_destino = fbd.SelectedPath;
```

Comment: Isso já foi tentado e não deu certo. Eu preciso do FolderBrowserDialog, pois o que preciso é selecionar uma pasta de trabalho.

Comment: Fiz uma edição e pus o código original. O código anterior era o da segunda tentaiva e estava errado.

Comment: e se você setar para Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop ? acredito que funcione

Comment: estranho mesmo, mas modifique essa linha, fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer; altere MyComputer para Desktop

Comment: Começo a desconfiar do meu ambiente, visual studio e etc.. Vou fazer o seguinte. Vou fixar o Folder no código, primeiro, fazer as alterações que necessito, depois volto o código e compilo e mando para a homologação e ver se vai dar o mesmo problema. Caso não aconteça, aí terei a certeza que é meu ambiente. Se sim, aí uso o tempo restante para entender e resolver esse problema.